# Parcel When I press the onclick event button so, undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, parceljs

I'm building separate components for my personal portfolio using **ParcelJS**
I'm attaching the [Project Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8gw2.png) working tree. Also, Remainder that don't worry about public and build folder. If I run the scripts using yarn. It will automatically create the folder.
Now I have created a Header Component filename *header.js*

```
export function Header() {
  return `
  <nav class="nav__bar">
    <button class="nav__bar__burger" onclick="ToggleClassMenu()">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </button>
  </nav>
  `;
}
```

Now I need to register or connect the component with an HTML file using **JavaScript.**
filename *app.js*

```
import { Header } from "./components/header";
function App() {
  document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = Header();
}
//Initialize the App
App();
```

Now I have created HTML filename *index.html*
Also, these codes are inside the body tag.

```
<noscript>You need to enable the JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<header class="nav" id="nav"></header>
<script src="../app.js"></script>
<script src="../app-functions.js"></script>
```

*package.json* scripts code

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "parcel ./src/pages/*.html --out-dir public -p 3030 watch --no-cache --no-source-maps",
    "build": "parcel build ./src/pages/*.html --out-dir build --public-url ./ --no-cache --no-source-maps"
  }
```

Now I am creating for Header Component Which has a button `onclick` event ToggleClassMenu function so I need to create a separate file. filename *header-comps.js*

```
export function ToggleClassMenu() {
    console.log('Working Toggle Class');
}
```

filename *app-functions.js*
`import "./functions/header-comps";`
The problem ToggleClassMenu is undefined when someone presses the button. I don't know where I need to put the code.
If I add the code **ToggleClassMenu()** in the Header Component filename *header.js* so, still undefined when someone presses the button.
 **Note: I don't want this.** If I add the code **ToggleClassMenu()** in HTML file before closing the body tag as a script tag. It is fully working fine.
 **Note: I want this.** I want to create a separate JS file because every separate code JS file module is readable and easy to change the code. How to fix the issue ToggleClassMenu undefined.
At last, I know that we need to load the HTML document first and then javascript will be loaded.

Comment: When you use `onclick="someFunction()"`, that function must be available in the **global scope**. In other words, it's as if it was written `onclick="window.someFunction()"`

Comment: as you said `onclick="window.ToggleClassMenu()"` so, still undefined. do you have any other solutions how to fix it?

Comment: No no, your function is *not* in the global scope; that's the problem. You have to put it there directly. When you import it into your top-level module, it won't be global.

Comment: Where I need to put the code that's can be globally accessible.

Comment: If you import the function, you can explicitly use `window.ToggleClassMenu = ToggleClassMenu;` to make it visible. It would be better to find a cleaner way of assigning event handlers, but that should work.